# HOW do I write from a Spartan6 to the Micron external Cellular RAM on the Nexys3 FPGA Board?

Tags: vhdl, ram, fpga, xilinx

I have looked everywhere, the datasheet, the Xilinx website, digilent, etc. etc. and can't find anything!  I was able to use the Adept tool to verify that my Cellular RAM is functioning correctly, but I just can't find any stock VHDL code as a controller to write data to and read data from it!!  Help!!

Comment: From a Stack Exchange item [Accesing the PCM Flash Memory on a Nexys 3 Board](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34807/accesing-the-pcm-flash-memory-on-a-nexys-3-board), try looking in [Samuirai/fpga/Memory](https://github.com/Samuirai/fpga/tree/master/Memory) github repository for something with .vhd suffix.  There's also [Nexys 3 Design Review](http://homepages.wmich.edu/~bazuinb/ECE6050/Nexys%203%20Design%20Review.pdf) which indicates it can be accessed with an SRAM interaface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this link but it's for asynchronous mode, which is not nearly fast enough:
http://embsi.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-use-cellular-ram-from-micron.html

Eventually found this on the Nexys 2 Digilent page:
http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=NEXYS2
under
"Onboard Memory controller reference design"
It's just a shame that this was not included with Nexys 3 details as it would have saved a lot of time!
Hopefully somebody else with this issue could at least find what I posted here and find it quickly...

Comment: The link to the Nexys 2 Diglient page in the post seems to have changed... Sadly, I don't see any good way to stop this happening in the future, but here is the new link: https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/nexys-2/start